# Trying to understand how WSL2 networking and routing works when pinging google.com, confused

Tags: networking, routing, windows-subsystem-for-linux, nat, wireshark

I'm trying to learn networking and i'm still a novice. I'm confused about how the routing is done between the virtual adapter and my wifi card

When I ping google.com from WSL, I can see on Wireshark on my WSL virtual adapter the request going from 172.30.85.15 (My WSL virtual adapter) to 142.250.178.131 ( google.com )

Wireshark => WSL Adapter:
[image: Wireshark => WSL Adapter]

I can also see at the same time my request going from my Wireless card adapter (192.168.157.57) to 142.250.178.131 when monitoring my Wireless Card.

Wireframe => WiFi Card:
[image: Wireframe => WiFi Card]

I'm guessing this is thanks to the windows routing table:
[image: Routing table]
, the request goes through the WSL virtual adapter first, then gets forwarded to my interface at 192.168.157.57
The request then take 192.168.157.57 as the "origin"

Then when the reponse comes back, it goes to the 192.168.157.57 and that's where I get confused. I know somehow the 172.30.95.255 route is being used, but how exactly does the response go from 192.168.157.57 from 172.30.95.255 if the response final destination (as written in the destination field in wireshark) targets my wifi card ? I don't see any packet going from my wifi card to my virtual adapter.

I don't understand how this can work, if I try to delete the 172.30.x.x routes, it stops working which means they are being used.

Comment: That's just… NAT. Have you researched that topic yet? Do you have a more specific question?

Comment: @DanielB I thought I had it but no. I'm probably missing something.
My question is, if my ping reply destination is my Wifi Card ( 192.168.x.x ), why and how is it being "forwarded" to the WSL adapter ?
If the ping final destination is 192.168.x.x, my undestanding is that it should stop when it reaches 192.168.x.x but that's not the case, I can see the ping reply on the WSL adapter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works the same way as in your home router. With the default vSwitch configuration [that WSL2 creates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/user-guide/setup-nat-network), your host OS practically becomes a router **with a stateful NAT feature** – NAT because it also rewrites (translates) the IP addresses on the outbound packets, hiding the WSL network, and stateful because it keeps track of all flows (such as TCP connections) that go through it, allowing it to automatically perform the opposite translation for inbound reply packets.

That is, when you send the initial ICMP packet from WSL (or a UDP packet for a more typical example), the Hyper-V NAT function remembers the mapping it just did:

| Type | Orig source | Orig dest | Expected reply source | Expected reply dest |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ICMP | 172.30.85.15 | 142.250.178.131 | 142.250.178.131 | 192.168.157.57 |
| TCP | 172.30.85.15:23456 | 8.8.8.8:53 | 8.8.8.8:53 | 192.168.157.57:34567 |

so that when a reply comes in, it'll look for matching "Expected reply" fields and restore the original source/dest fields (only swapped because it's a reply) **before** routing the packet, and therefore before the "is this a local address" check.

(This is a simplified example. There's usually more information in the state table, e.g. different ICMP "pings" are tracked by their IDs, while different TCP or UDP flows are tracked by port numbers; and of course there are timeouts for cleaning up expired entries.)

Use `Get-NetNatSession` to see the Hyper-V NAT states on Windows (or `conntrack -L` to see the iptables/nftables states on Linux). The example was modeled after conntrack, but the fields in Hyper-V NAT are similar.

Comment: Thank you ! Your answer was extremely clear and useful.
There's still something I don't really get about it, I thought the vSwitch / NAT was the WSL Virtual Adapter (not my host OS ?) and that it was the one using the mapping table you mentionned.

Comment: The virtual interface you see inside WSL is on the other end of the cable, so to speak. You could literally imagine a vSwitch as a physical Ethernet switch, where one cable goes to the router (host OS) and another goes to WSL (or some other Hyper-V VM).